# My Play! process stops as soon as I close the console

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to deploy and run a POC WS on my server.
The WS works fine on my dev computer.I package the app using the dist command.
I upload and unzip everything on the server, then I start the server using myApp& command.
But as soon as I close the connection to my server the web server stops...

It shouldn't be attached to my console... How can I fix this ?

Comment: I can add the nohup call myself but I was hoping it was done by the myApp generated start script...

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm adding another script called with nohup but that's too bad it's not the default behavior